# jQuery remove element with next() and remove()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using jQuery to remove an element with the class named "`added`" There are multiple elements with this class name.

```
$(".steps-row-first").on("change", ".anotherCheese", function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'no') {
         $(this).parent().next(".added").remove();
    }
    else
    {
         $(".steps-row-first").append("<div class='added'></div>");
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="steps-row-first">
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="radio-wrapper">
         <div class="radio-group">
            <input type="radio" class="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="yes">
            <label>Yes</label>
         </div>
         <div class="radio-group">
            <input type="radio" class="anotherCheese" name="anotherCheese" value="no">
            <label>No</label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
   <div class="added"></div>
</div>
```

When I click the no radio button the element does not get removed, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: could you explain what is the `.steps-row-first` element , or show the whole html please

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is wrong for removing the element. In `$(this).parent().next(".added").remove();`, `$(this)` is the input element, so it's parent is just the `.radio-group` element. You need to change it to `$(this).parents('.radio-wrapper').next(".added").remove();`

Even above will not work because there is a `<div>` between `.radio-wrapper` and `.added`, to make it work, you need to use `next()` twice:  `$(this).parents('.radio-wrapper').next().next(".added").remove();`

Comment: This did not work

Comment: I updated my question with more details and code

Comment: Updated my answer to fix bug

Comment: Still did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I dont know , where what's exactly the `.steps-row-first` the element

but try using parents to get back then chose the parent's siblings to target your div with added class as below:

```
....
if($(this).val() == 'no') {
     $(this).parents(".form-group").siblings(".added").remove();
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".steps-row-first").on("change", ".anotherCheese", function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'no') {
         $(".steps-row-first").find(".added").remove();
    }
    else
    {
         $(".steps-row-first").append("<div class='added'></div>");
    }
});
```

you can use find() to find all class .added and remove it